# What happens when there is a tie for PotW

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

Looking at this weeks contest, I noticed the top two photos are on the same score. If this continues to be the case ther will be a tie. What happens when this happens? who decides who wins?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's happened before.  If it ends in a tie, then they both win.  We run the next contest for 2 weeks and each winner gets 1 week in the spotlight.

Comment: Thanks, it is a good way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I always reserve my vote for the end as a tie-breaker. Generally speaking, I can break them...although there have been occasions where I liked both winners, and we do what @rfusca stated.