# New Photo Contest

Tags: discussion, featured-photo, contest

Announcing the new Photo Contest! Rather than maintain a long ongoing contest in Meta as was done for nearly a decade, we have shifted to periodic themed contests over on the main site.

#### [Submit a photo to the current contest on Main](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/129502/). Do not post submissions to this Meta post.

---

The old [Weekly Featured Image Contest](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) has been shut down. After running for nearly a decade, it produced tons of great submissions that were featured on the main site every week. Thanks to everybody who submitted and/or voted on photos over the years in that contest.

The new contest is intended to reward submitters more immediately, as the contest submission and voting is more periodic. Rather than a single long-ongoing contest, new contests are limited in time (and possibly theme) to encourage and reward recent posters.

Initially, the new contest is envisioned to run approximately every 2 weeks, ending on a Monday at 12:01 AM UTC (midnight between Sunday and Monday, UTC). At that time, the winning submission will be accepted on the contest page, posted in the Photo of the Week sidebar and in the [Hall of Fame](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/708). The 2nd-highest voted submission will be featured in the PotW sidebar and Hall of Fame the subsequent week.

**Contest themes will be selected from the highest-voted idea at the  [Photo of the Week Theme Ideas](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1740/) thread.**

---

### General contest rules (the same for each contest)

The rules below will be stated in each weekly/bi-weekly/monthly contest; they are quoted here for reference.

> #### Voting Rules
>
> - View the submissions [sorted by active] to give every submitter a fair chance
> - Vote up as many images as you like
> - Please, **up votes only!** Do NOT vote down your competitors! If you don't like an image, don't vote
> - **Voting closes on [date, usually a Monday] at 12:01 AM UTC** (00:01 UTC if you prefer a 24-hour time). The winner will be chosen based on votes at that time.
>
> #### Submission Rules
>
> 1. One photo submission per answer. Up to three (3) entries allowed.
> 2. Post only photos taken by yourself or the person with you.
> 3. **All entries should include:**
>
>    - a **title** for the photo
>    - a **location and date**, if known
>    - **camera, lens, and exposure settings**, if known
>    - any other explanatory notes, comments, etc., that you want to include (completely optional)
> 4. The submitted image must conform to this site's content license, >Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 4.0 ([CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)) with [attribution required](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/).
> 5. Do not use this as a forum for photo critique. Use [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=photo.stackexchange.com) instead, or [ask a new question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) about your image.
>
> ---
>
> #### Next Contest
>
> Suggest a theme by writing a new answer at the [Photo of the Week Theme Ideas](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1740/) thread. Please make sure to check the [PotW theme ideas Archive](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1741/) first, to make sure you aren't recycling a theme.
>
> The highest-voted theme will be the next theme.
>
> Good luck!

Comment: What is the official procedure for breaking a tie? Particularly when it is for second place?

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to propose that in the event of a tie for second place so that there are more than two images in the top two numerical scores, rather than one person arbitrarily selecting one image and totally ignoring the other(s), there be a tiebreaker determined by total number of votes for all images submitted by each user for that contest cycle.

At the very least, two images with the same score should both be included in the Hall of Fame if either image is.

Comment: I didn't notice it when I grabbed the PotW image last night, but yeah, your photo had the same number of total upvotes. To be clear (and it hasn't been an issue yet), but total upvotes are what's counted, not net votes. Downvotes are ignored.

Comment: As a separate tangent, I notice now that depending on... luck of the draw? moon phase? ... I'm not sure, but if I refresh the photo contest page (still sorted by Votes), sometimes your submission is display before the other one with equal votes. SE doesn't seem to sort answers with equal votes based on something like earliest submission date. For normal Q&A submissions, that's a good thing, to apparently randomize otherwise "equal" (in vote terms) answers.

Comment: So what is the official procedure for breaking a tie?

Comment: For the time being, I think I'm going to follow what [rfusca did in the past](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2434/11924): just holding over the contest for another week, and post the tie breakers. Since we've been doing the top 2 vote-getters for PotW (because the contests have been going every 2 weeks), if there's a tie for #1, nothing changes, both get featured. If there's a tie for #2/#3, then I'll just feature 3 total photos from a contest, 3 weeks in a row.

Comment: BTW, as far what jrista used to do (his answer below rfusca's in the link in the previous comment), I don't have any upvotes to withhold: as a matter of encouragement, I upvote pretty much every photo submission.

Answer (score 0):

I Think we should have users post there shooting mode that they used. I know it was suggested already that exposure is exposure regardless how they got it. but I think it would be very helpful to know what mode it was shot in.

You always see on the internet that people prefer to shoot in AV mode or manual. so if you see a picture in the competition and your like I'm wondering if he is shooting in this mode or that mode. I think it would start a good debate and people might try that mode if they are new to see what kind of creativity might come about it.

Comment: It makes no difference to the result what mode I use. If my concern in a shot is controlling the depth of field, is doesn't really matter if I set the aperture and then manually set the shutter by looking at the meter, or if the camera looks at the meter and sets it for me. The same with other modes. The difference when shooting is that if I think the scene will over or under exposed, I'd just adjust the shutter speed in manual mode, but in semi-auto I'd adjust the exposure compensation value instead. All you can glean from the mode I used is which setting I wanted to control myself.

Comment: Makes sense @LightBender Thanks for the feedback

Comment: If you want to learn about the camera modes and when to use them, [this question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/23398/which-mode-should-i-use-on-my-camera) has two excellent answers that should help you.

Comment: Thanks @LightBender I use AV most of the time learning it. When I had my powershot I was in full manual all the time. I know how to shoot in all modes but right now I’m trying to learn concepts and understanding before I start shooting again. I want to know why I got an exposure the way I did. I don’t know if that is the right way to go about it but I don’t know any other way. I’m on this site just asking and reading a lot