# Photo contest sidebar still links to the old, historically locked weekly ongoing contest here on meta

Tags: bug, contest

Per [New Photo Contest](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7109/new-photo-contest), the [weekly ongoing contest post](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) here on meta has been shut down, and competitions are now held on the main site.

However, the "Submit photo" link on the featured photo sidebar on the main site still links to the old post, which is now historically locked.

Can the link please be changed to the above former link, which is routinely edited to link to the current contest post on the main site?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for pointing that out. Ive fixed it to point to the new contest.

The reason that happened is that when updating the photo of the week sidebar, the form field for Contest URL is always pre-filled with the old photo contest url. I clearly forgot to paste in the new url, and then didn't check the preview thoroughly before posting it.